# dynamically added widgets inaccessable in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a  subclassed QToolButton(in a toolbar added to mainwindow with addToolBar() ) that works as a "drag and drop button" dynamically generating subclassed QWidgets( which contain  just 1 QTextEdit)  on the central Widget of a QMainWindow which is a QWidget. The drag and drop works fine.

However unless the user accesses them in a very specific order, only one of the QTextEdit widgets stays accessible after which the others do not respond to mouse clicks and **the whole central Widget is "stuck"**. 
By that i mean any other widgets who are children of the central widget are unresponsive.

Why is that? Does it have something to do with focus policies possibly?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to SpongeBobs comment, where he suggested to test plain QTextEdit generating instead of a whole custom class, we know that the error is somewhere in the custom class ideafield. So how do I change it to get the appropriate behavior?

```
#ifndef IDEAFIELD_H
#define IDEAFIELD_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QFrame>

class IdeaField : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IdeaField(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void move_all(int,int);
    void move_all(QPoint);

    QTextEdit *textField;
signals:

public slots:

};
```

code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
    ideaPlane = new IdeaPlane(this);
    setCentralWidget(ideaPlane);

    MainWindow::createToolBars();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::createToolBars()
{
    QToolBar * topToolBar = addToolBar(tr("Title"));
    dragIdeaButton = new dragButton(this);
    topToolBar->addWidget(dragIdeaButton);
}
```

ideafield.cpp: subclassed QTextEdit:

```
#include "ideafield.h"

IdeaField::IdeaField(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    textField = new QTextEdit(this);
    textField->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    textField->setPlainText(tr("TEST TEXT\nHURRAY!"));
}
void IdeaField::move_all(int x,int y)
{
    textField->move(x,y);
}
void IdeaField::move_all(QPoint point)
{
    textField->move(point);
}
```

Comment: I dont actualy understand about what you are asking but the possible sollusion is to add objectNames to items an acces to items through them. like: someInput->setObjectName("someInputXX");... toolBar->findChild<SomeInputType *>("someInputXX");

Comment: `textField = new QTextEdit(this);` Why your `QTextEdit` subclass contains another `QTextEdit`? I think your error is somehow linked with it

Comment: Uh oh, I need to see `ideafield.h`. Is it `QWidget` direct subclass? You said that it is `QTextEdit` subclass, but your code says that it is not. If it is subclass of QTextEdit, this line of code is wrong: `IdeaField::IdeaField(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)`

Comment: yes,sorry for that, it is subclass of QWidget,class IdeaField : public QWidget

Comment: I think you should try to substitute your `IdeaField`s with `QTextEdit`s, then if wrong behaviour will be gone, post all the code of `IdeaField`. We need to localize the error, there's no sence in watching all those files with so many classes

Comment: That made it behave correctly for some reason! But why should it matter that the QTextEdit is a part of a custom widget?

Comment: @StanislawT, I think it's better to make `IdeaField` a subclass of `QTextEdit`, all should work at that point. Also you can try just to temporary get rid of `move_all()` methods, maybe they work incorrectly somehow, I can't understand what kind of wrong behaviour you get.

Comment: The move_all methods are an overhead since there will be a lot of stuff moving in one ideafield. I plan to add more functionality to the IdeaField involving at least inserting images so I need to solve this problem in a way that does not restrict me in that direction.

Comment: @StanislawT, we need first to find what method make such a buggy behaviour, so I'd delete that `move_all()` methods just to watch if the problem will be gone. I don't see any obvious errors in a code, so we need to find out where the error is by experiments